# Spring security intercept-url root and login

Tags: spring, security, authentication, root, intercept

i want to secure everything except the root.. my security looks like this:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/"/>
<intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()" pattern="/**"/>
<form-login authentication-failure-url="/" login-page="/" default-target-url="/dashboard"/>
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/"/>
</http>
```

my login page is included in the root..
i'm getting a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error..

please can anybody help with this problem?

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Add bypass security check for login page